# Register multiple singletons with same interface but different constructor parameters

Tags: c#, azure, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I have 2 storage (Azure) accounts lets call them src and dest and I have controllers that require access to both and I'm trying to work out how to register these 2 singletons conditionally.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36630567/simple-injector-with-dependency-on-two-objects-that-implement-same-interface%20answer) gave me some hope but I can't quite work it out, what I want to do is something like (appreciate RegisterSingletonConditional isn't a valid fn):

```
IBlobAccessClient src = new BlobAccessClient(srcConnectionString);
IBlobAccessClient dest = new BlobAccessClient(destConnectionString);

container.RegisterSingletonConditional<IBlobAccessClient>(
   src,
   c => c.Consumer.Target.Parameter.Name.Contains("src"));

container.RegisterSingletonConditional<IBlobAccessClient>(
   dest,
   c => c.Consumer.Target.Parameter.Name.Contains("dest"));
```

Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: Although RegisterSingletonConditional does not exist, the predicate looks fine by me, what is the exact problem you're facing?

Comment: My problem is I can't work out how to get the syntax right (or if it's possible) for the actual container.RegisterConditional function to work when I want to pass it an instance like above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a non-generic `RegisterConditional` overload that accepts a `Registration` object. You can wrap your `BlobAccessClient` instance in a `Registration` and pass it on to `RegisterConditional` as shown here:

```
container.RegisterConditional(typeof(IBlobAccessClient),
    Lifestyle.Singleton.CreateRegistration(
        () => new BlobAccessClient(srcConnectionString), container),
    c => c.Consumer.Target.Parameter.Name.Contains("src"));

container.RegisterConditional(typeof(IBlobAccessClient),
    Lifestyle.Singleton.CreateRegistration(
        () => new BlobAccessClient(destConnectionString), container),
    c => c.Consumer.Target.Parameter.Name.Contains("dest"));
```

If this is a common pattern, you can simplify your code a bit by defining a simple extension method as follows:

```
public static void RegisterConditionalInstance<TService>(
    this Container container, TService instance, Predicate<PredicateContext> predicate)
    where TService : class
{
    container.RegisterConditional(typeof(TService),
        Lifestyle.Singleton.CreateRegistration(() => instance, container),
        predicate);
}
```

This allows you to reduce the previous configuration to the following:

```
container.RegisterConditionalInstance<IBlobAccessClient>(
    new BlobAccessClient(srcConnectionString),
    c => c.Consumer.Target.Parameter.Name.Contains("src"));

container.RegisterConditionalInstance<IBlobAccessClient>(
    new BlobAccessClient(destConnectionString),
    c => c.Consumer.Target.Parameter.Name.Contains("dest"));
```

Optionally, you can simplify the predicate by extracting this to a simple method as well:

```
private static Predicate<PredicateContext> InjectedIntoTargetNamed(string targetName) =>
    c => c.Consumer.Target.Name.Contains(targetName);
```

This reduces the registration to the following:

```
container.RegisterConditionalInstance<IBlobAccessClient>(
    new BlobAccessClient(srcConnectionString),
    InjectedIntoTargetNamed("src"));

container.RegisterConditionalInstance<IBlobAccessClient>(
    new BlobAccessClient(destConnectionString),
    InjectedIntoTargetNamed("dest"));
```

Comment: Thanks will give it a spin it's perfect for my main controllers, one question, I additionally have some legacy code in another app that has a nasty hacked di setup where it's passing the container around and then doing var x = container.GetInstance<IBlobAccessClient>(); I note that the Consumer would be null in this instance as I'm getting it direct from the container, is there any way I can get the container to give me the one I want based on the above. Failing that I'm going to have to deal with the legacy code another way!

Comment: @Simon: Your question is unclear to me. If this is a new question, please post a new question with additional code and details here on Stackoverflow.

Comment: It's more an extension, I think, but I'll add it as a new question for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest defining two new interfaces:

```
public interface IBlobAccessClientSource : IBlobAccessClient
{ }

public interface IBlobAccessClientDestination : IBlobAccessClient
{ }
```

And then registering them both individually (in whatever way that SimpleInject supports).

Then in your consumers, inject in `IBlobAccessClientSource` and / or `IBlobAccessClientDestination` as needed. *This will ensure that there are two singleton registrations - one for each of the two interfaces.*

Comment: Thanks, the "alias" interfaces was my fallback option it just felt a bit dirty/hacky?

Comment: Yeah it is a bit hacky - but it is **clear** which is what I like. The consumer at least easily knows what they are getting...

Comment: Agreed on the clear part so if there is no "proper" way to do it that'll have to be my fallback, thanks.

Comment: The 'alias' interface is not a hack persee. The question you should ask yourself is whether injecting the 'wrong' `BlobAccessClient` instance would break the consuming class or not. If it _does_ break the consumer, this means you are violating the [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), which means defining two separate interface _is_ actually _the_ solution. If the consumer however keeps working, LSP is _not_ violated and in that case, go for [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47553097/264697).