# Simple Injector and Strategy pattern (Register dependency runtime based on request)

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I am working on Simple injector DI library. I need good ideas on how to register interface which is consumed in more than one provider (component).

Below is my requirement.

It is Web API project where I have a `BaggageController` class which will get a request for `Add Baggage` operation, Based on a provider from the request I have to route the request to concerned class. A Provider can be an `Airline A` or `Airline B`.

Request for AddBaggage(BaggageRequest, Provider) from client
--> BaggageController --> Business.Baggage.Implementation (Decision) --> Call Provider A
--> Call Provider B

Below is the code I am registering with Simple injector.

```
container.Register<IBaggageService, BaggageService>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.Register<IFlightService, ProviderA>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
// This next line throws an error as IFlightService is already registered.
container.Register<IFlightService, ProviderB>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

Since my decision would be taken at runtime, I can not use the RegisterConditional method.

Is there any other way to register dependency at runtime using Simple Injector?

Comment: Take a look on the [documentation](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto.html#resolve-instances-by-key)

Comment: Please show the code that shows how you decide which provider to call.

Comment: Besides the page @RomanKoliada pointed at, also take a look at [conditional registrations](https://simpleinjector.org/advanced#context-based-injection) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47551425/simple-injector-register-multiple-singletons-with-same-interface-but-different-c) recent question on this subject.