# Get Conditional Instances from Simple Injector container

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

Following on from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47551425/simpleinject-register-multiple-singletons-with-same-interface-but-different-cons) discussion, I also have some legacy code that rather than doing DI properly has passed the container around the application, I think this is because of some generic/factory/dynamic code that meant when they did this it was easier for them to pass the container around than rewrite the entire system!

They then simply got what they needed from the container instance when they needed it. i.e.

```
public class SomeStageInAPipeline :
{
    private readonly IBlobAccessClient _blobAccessClient;

    public SomeStageInAPipeline (Container container)
    {
        _blobAccessClient = container.GetInstance<IBlobAccessClient>();
    }
```

This is fine until we have the scenario of instances registered conditionally, i.e.

```
container.RegisterConditional(typeof(IBlobAccessClient),
    Lifestyle.Singleton.CreateRegistration(
        () => new BlobAccessClient(srcConnectionString), container),
    c => c.Consumer.Target.Parameter.Name.Contains("src"));

container.RegisterConditional(typeof(IBlobAccessClient),
    Lifestyle.Singleton.CreateRegistration(
        () => new BlobAccessClient(destConnectionString), container),
    c => c.Consumer.Target.Parameter.Name.Contains("dest"));
```

I can set one as the default, i.e.

```
container.RegisterConditional(typeof(IBlobAccessClient),
    Lifestyle.Singleton.CreateRegistration(
        () => new BlobAccessClient(srcConnectionString), container),
    c => c.Handled == false);
```

which works fine for the existing requests to `GetInstance(<IBlobAccessClient>)` but I've no idea how I would access the other "dest" instance or if it's even possible.

**UPDATE** What I want to be able to do is:

```
public class SomeStageInAPipeline :
{
    private readonly IBlobAccessClient _srcBlobAccessClient;
    private readonly IBlobAccessClient _destBlobAccessClient;

    public SomeStageInAPipeline (Container container)
    {
        _srcBlobAccessClient = container.GetInstance<IBlobAccessClient>();
        // obviously the below just gets me the default instance
        _destBlobAccessClient = container.GetInstance<IBlobAccessClient>();
    }
```

Comment: Can you show how and where you want to access the "dest" instance?

Comment: Updated original, thanks, oops fixed the mistake in the original update of not adding the variable declaration!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A registration is conditional based on its context. When you resolve directly from the `Container` however, you lose all possible contextual information. The resolved type becomes a new *root type*. That's one of the many reasons why injecting the `Container` directly is a [really bad idea](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/).

You could inject inject some sort of `Func<string, IBlobAccessClient>` delegate instead, but since you are making changes to `SomeStageInAPipeline` already, refactor directly to **Constructor Injection** as follows:

```
public class SomeStageInAPipeline
{
    private readonly IBlobAccessClient _srcBlobAccessClient;
    private readonly IBlobAccessClient _destBlobAccessClient;

    public SomeStageInAPipeline(
        IBlobAccessClient srcBlobAccessClient,
        IBlobAccessClient destBlobAccessClient)
    {
        _srcBlobAccessClient = srcBlobAccessClient;
        _destBlobAccessClient = destBlobAccessClient;
    }
}
```

When you resolve `SomeStageInAPipeline` from the `Container`, either by calling `GetInstance<SomeStageInAPipeline>()` or by injecting it into a consumer, Simple Injector will build up the expected object graph with those conditionals for you.

**UPDATE**:

If changing the constructor signature of `SomeStageInAPipeline` is not possible at this point in time, consider moving the `IBlobAccessClient` parameters into a Parameter Object and resolve that parameter object from the `Container`:

```
public sealed class BlobAccessClients
{
    public readonly IBlobAccessClient Src;
    public readonly IBlobAccessClient Dest;

    public BlobAccessClients(IBlobAccessClient src, IBlobAccessClient dest)
    {
        this.Src = src;
        this.Dest = dest;
    }
}
```

This allows you to change the `SomeStageInAPipeline` to the following:

```
public class SomeStageInAPipeline
{
    private readonly IBlobAccessClient _srcBlobAccessClient;
    private readonly IBlobAccessClient _destBlobAccessClient;

    public SomeStageInAPipeline (Container container)
    {
        var clients = container.GetInstance<BlobAccessClients>();
        _srcBlobAccessClient = clients.Src;
        _destBlobAccessClient = clients.Dest;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the issue is this is just one stage in a huge legacy app and I lack the c# chops to properly explain why a refactor to Constructor Injection isn't a simple job, it's something to do with the way the existing code builds a dynamic list of stages to execute at runtime based on the type of message it's processing. It's long overdue a full rewrite but I/we lack the time to do that so for now will have to just make the ugly code a bit uglier and create a new instance directly in the constructor each time and take the hit! Thanks for your help though!

Comment: interesting I'll give this a spin and see how I get on and update accordingly, thanks again.

Comment: works like a charm and it stops the ugly code from getting any worse and as a colleague just said "clean and simple, I like it"

Comment: As long as you realize this _is_ an intermediate solution.